# flex mobile keyup event

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

when testing on **ipad/iphone real devices**, this snippet :

```
<s:TextInput id="search_txt" keyUp="search_txt_keyUpHandler(event)" />
```

simply does not react.

**I also tried to add a global stage event keyphandler with no luck.**

This works fine on Air and Android.

Any idea ?

Comment: It does not react how?  You mean the keyUp event is not dispatched?  Or something else?  Which version of AIR are you using?  Which version if iOS are you using?

Comment: no event dispatched. I am using the Air3.5.
It ONLY happens on IOS (ipad3, ipad1, iphone4).
Works fine on Air and on Android.